# Gradle plugin project version number

Tags: plugins, gradle

I have a gradle plugin that uses the `project.version` variable.

How ever, the version in the plugin does not update when I change the version in the `build.gradle` file.

## To illustrate:

### plugin

```
// my-plugin
void apply(Project project) {
  project.tasks.create(name: 'printVersionFromPlugin') {
    println project.version
  }
}
```

### build.gradle

```
version '1.0.1' // used to be 1.0.0

task printVersion {
  println project.version
}

apply plugin: 'my-plugin'
```

### Result

```
> gradle printVersion
1.0.1
> gradle printVersionFromPlugin
1.0.0
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both the build script and the plugin make the same mistake. They print the version as part of configuring the task, rather than giving the task a behavior (task action). If the plugin is applied before the version is set in the build script (which is normally the case), it will print the previous value of the `version` property (perhaps one is set in `gradle.properties`).

Correct task declaration:

```
task printVersion {
    // any code that goes here is part of configuring the task
    // this code will always get run, even if the task is not executed
    doLast { // add a task action
        // any code that goes here is part of executing the task
        // this code will only get run if and when the task gets executed
        println project.version
    }
}
```

Same for the plugin's task.

Comment: To get just the version printed and not other gradle stuff use: `./gradlew -q printVersion`.
And preferred notation is `tasks.register('printVersion') {` instead of `task printVersion {`.

Answer (score 61):

You can use gradle properties to extract project version without adding a dedicated task to the build.gradle file.

For example:

```
gradle properties -q | awk '/^version:/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: Better `./gradlew properties --no-daemon --console=plain -q | grep "^version:" | awk '{printf $2}'` in case there's multiple versions. Also you don't need a running daemon for that.

Comment: I prefer this solution because it doesn't require changing the build file, which I don't necessarily own.

Comment: This is the WRONG solution ever to this problem: in Gradle, the version is an object, not a string. The resulting string containing the version is simply the result of  `toString()` on the Version object assigned to to  ` project.version`.

Using things like grep/awk and so on to parse a build.gradle file is ever the wrong solution. It's like parsing an XML using grep.

See https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/09/gradle-goodness-using-objects-for.html

Comment: For those who goes with this solution, don't forget to add a caret in the beginning of grep. You might have other properties ending with "version:" ( grep "^version:" ).

Comment: @Vinz486 — If all you're doing is verifying the version manually to ensure it looks right, a quick hacky solution that nonetheless gets the right answer is fine, and arguably more ideal than a bullet-proof solution that uses the API correctly but requires changes/configuration to the source.  So I'd argue that depending on the context, it's not necessarily "WRONG"; same with your example of parsing the `build.gradle` with grep/awk and so on or XML using grep.

Comment: yes, the version is an object, but if I set that version to a String object, then it is particularly fine. Also, the solution does use the api. It is clearly asking gradle what it thinks the version is and the reply is defines to be a key value pair with a colon separator, which is what grep/awk were built for. Obviously, this solution does not work for you if you set your version to a complex object.

Comment: As of Gradle 7.5, you can limit Gradle itself to a given property: `./gradlew -q :properties --property version`. Unfortunately, that still prints a "Root project" header and a "version: " prefix.