# How can I read Gradle metadata in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Within my Jenkinsfile I would like to read some metadata from a Gradle buildscript, e.g. `group`, `baseName`and `version`. With Maven, I can do something like this:

```
def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
env.POM_VERSION         = pom.version
env.POM_ARTIFACT_ID     = pom.artifactId
env.POM_GROUP_ID        = pom.groupId
```

Question is: how can I do the same thing with Gradle, given I have a `build.gradle` that looks like this:

```
ext {
    group = 'my.group.com'
    baseName = 'myapplication'
    version = '0.5.2-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Maybe there is a "trick" to read Gradle build information in a `Jenkinsfile` since both is Groovy, but I am a Groovy newb :)

Comment: try to [readFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) and find the relevant text

Comment: An option would be to use `gradle.properties` and the [`readProperties`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readproperties-code-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) step. Could possibly help by knowing exactly what you are trying to do in your `Jenkinsfile`.

Comment: I'm trying to create a versioned jar artifact that I can then upload to Artifactory. Therefore I need the version and artifact name to add the build number and then push it to the repo. Maybe it's also possible to do this completely in Gradle - but as I said: I'm a Gradle newb :)

Comment: ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140744/get-gradle-variables-in-jenkins-pipeline-script?rq=1