# In groovy how can I get value of a key from build.gradle extra properties

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a Gradle project,
And I want to get a specific value from the build.gradle file using groovy
(it's a jenkins job ).

***build.gradle:***

```
allprojects {
    subprojects {
        version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
        if (project.hasProperty("TestVersion"))
            version = project."TestVersion"


    }


    ext {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
        springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'
        TestVersion = '4.0.0-SNAPSHOT'


    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
        maven {
            url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/'
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the **"TestVersion"** version  (which is 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT) in a "gradle" way if it is possible and not by a groovy script that just parses a json file.
Is there a way to do it or should I just start parsing it as a regular json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle files are written in Groovy syntax, not json. You cannot (and should not) easily parse any gradle file.

You can move the TestVersion value to a normal property file in your project, and [read that file from both your Jenkins script and your build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101589/how-to-read-a-properties-files-and-use-the-values-in-project-gradle-script), using a standard properties file parser.

Another alternative is to create a gradle task to help with whatever you want to do in Jenkins, and call gradle from within Jenkins.

As a similar example, you can [use the "gradle properties" command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48616954/2986984) to read properties from gradle.